# Extracting data from sites

Tags: java

I want to extract data from sites. I already got information from sites using the article extractor but now I want to get the information about events of  a particular place. I want to get the events in that place when I give location as input.For example I want to extract information from this site "http://www.indianevents.org/events-Rajasthan-14.htm" I could be able to extract all events,festivals etc.

```
URL url;
url = new URL(str);
InputSource is = HTMLFetcher.fetch(url).toInputSource();      
BoilerpipeSAXInput in = new BoilerpipeSAXInput(is);
TextDocument doc = in.getTextDocument();       
news=ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(doc);
```

Comment: basically you want to parse the output ??

Comment: yes I want to extract all details like events,festivals,exhibitions etc when I give particular place as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- consider [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to download the text content
- you can use [stanford pos tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/downloads/tagger.shtml) to parse the text into
  meaningful sentences
- and NLP can help identify event information.

although writing this might sound simple (trust me its difficult).
Good Luck. :)